# What keyboard layout is this?

Tags: keyboard-layout

[image: Gtune i5900]

Generic 101-key PC works fine, but the left button beside number 1 is not backquote(`)/tilde(~), and shift+2 is not at(@) ,i kinda miss those buttons.

Answer (score 1):

All praise Wikipedia, it seems to be [Japanese with Hiragana keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Japanese).

Answer (score 0):

According to [IBM](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/topics/keyboards/physical.html), that is likely a japanese 106-key layout.

If you use the X server and want to type in characters that are not available on the keyboard (eg. Unicode characters that you use regularly) or if you want to change the mapping of a character to another key (eg. have '@' on Shift+2), you can use the `xmodmap` command (you can use `xmodmap -pke` to get the currently used mapping).

Comment: In terms of physical layout, there are **107** keys in the photograph in front of us.  One can count them.  ☺  In terms of what software sees, this is to the operating system a **109**-key keyboard, with the two extra "Super" (a.k.a. "GUI" a.k.a. "Windows") keys, and the various Japanese "Intl" and "Lang" keys.  One of the logically present "Super" keys is physically missing, however, and some of those software-visible 109 keys (such as Scroll Lock) are doubled up onto existing physical keys.